# AEM Launch - Is there a way to rollout a launch?

Tags: adobe, aem, launch, blueprint, rollout

Are there some cases of using the launch method of AEM and promote it from the blueprint to all the other languages ?

Because, when doing a launch on the blueprint, it won't appear on the live copies. If you do a rollout of the blueprint with the launch, it won't appear in the live copies. The launch is not rolled out to the live copies.

Has anyone faced this case ?

Thank you

I tried to rollout the blueprint with the launch to the live copies but the launch didn't follow the rollout.